# Bowing at borechu with the shaliach tzibbur

Tags: minhag, chazzan-prayer-leader, minyan, bowing-kneeling

I've seen some people bowing at the same time as the shaliach tzibbur while he's saying "borechu" and then bowing again after for boruch hashem etc.
What is the source of the practice for this first bow with the chazan ?

Comment: Do you know a source fr the second bow that you ask only about the first? If so please [edit] it in as it could help people in their research

Comment: Follow up to @DoubleAA - Why is it necessary to bow down at all? Or is it a minhag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This [site](http://forum.otzar.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=17&t=12086) has a response regarding bowing with the Chazzan:

> ראה לדוגמא **בפירושי התפילה לרוקח, קדיש עמוד רמט**
>   
> 'על כן הקהל כופפין הקומה בשעה שהחזן אומ' ברכו על שם עבדו את ה' ביראה' עכ"ל.‏

It claims the source is a [Rokach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eleazar_of_Worms), who was a [Rishon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Rishonim), and he cites a Pasuk as the source of the custom in his [work on the Siddur](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/49925).

This [site](http://halachayomit.co.il/he/ReadHalacha.aspx?halachaid=500) has an answer to the bowing for the congregation's response:

> ולגבי **הכריעה באמירת ברוך ה' המבורך**, נזכר מנהג כזה בדברי הראשונים, במחזור ויטרי, ובספר ארחות חיים ועוד. והגאון המשנה ברורה הביא שבספר מגן גבורים נדחק הרבה למצוא טעם למנהג זה, והמשנה ברורה עצמו (בביאור הלכה סי' קיג) הביא סמך לזה מן הפסוק בדברי הימים (א' פכ"ט) "ויאמר דוד לכל הקהל, ברכו נא את ה' אלהיכם, ויברכו כל הקהל לה' אלהי אבותיהם, ויקדו וישתחוו לה' ולמלך". וכמה מן האחרונים הביאו עוד טעמים למנהג זה. אמנם בספר מקור חיים להגאון רבי יאיר בכרך כתב, שבכל הוספת כריעות שלא נזכרו בתלמוד, יש חשש איסור של מוסיף על תקנות חז"ל בכריעות, וכן כתב בספר שלחן טהור, שאין לנהוג במנהגי הכריעות הללו, ובהגהה שם כתב שלא מצינו מקור נכון למנהג זה, ובטעות יסודו. גם הגאון רבי בן ציון אבא שאול זצ"ל היה סובר שאין לכרוע בברכו, מפני שיש בזה חשש הוספה על תקנות חז"ל בכריעות.‏

Essentially, bowing at Borchu is a Minhag mentioned by the Rishonim like the Machzor Vitri and others.

The Mishna Brura even mentions that this custom may be based on another Pasuk.

Other Poskim claim that any bowing not mentioned in Shas is incorrect behaviour.

It also seems to be an Ashkenazi Minhag, as the Sephardim sit for Borchu, if they so want. (ibid)

<sup>I found these by [Googling](https://www.google.co.il/search?q=%D7%9C%D7%9B%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A2%20%D7%91%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%9B%D7%95&hl=iw&biw=&bih=&gbv=2&oq=%D7%9C%D7%9B%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A2%20%D7%91%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%9B%D7%95&gs_l=heirloom-serp.12...0.0.0.5377.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1ac..34.heirloom-serp..0.0.0.ya_Wk5qcCRA) and did not investigate the sites.</sup>